# C++ template with 'const'

Tags: c++, templates, constants, derived-class

Consider the following template class:

```
template <typename T> class Function {
public:
    virtual float eval( const T &x, const T &y ) = 0;
};
```

Since the 'eval' function should not modify the value of the two inputs 'x' and 'y', I put them as 'const'.
Then I create the following class derived from Function

```
class Foo1 : public Function <float*> {
public:
    Foo1() : Function <float*> () {}
    virtual float eval( const float* &x, const float* &y ) { ... }
};
```

When I compile with g++, I get the following warning:

```
hidden overloaded virtual function 'Function<float *>::eval' declared here: type mismatch at 1st parameter
      ('float *const &' vs 'const float *&')
        virtual float eval( const T &x, const T &y ) = 0;
```

And I cannot instantiate the class Foo1. The compiler says that the function 'eval' is not implemented. 
To make the compiler happy, the derived class must be as follows:

```
class Foo2 : public Function <float*> {
public:
    Foo2() : Function <float*> () {}
    virtual float eval( float* const &x, float* const &y ) { ... }
};
```

Foo2::eval function uses two parameters of type 'float * const' instead of 'const float *'. In other words, Foo2::eval can modify the content of the arrays 'x' and 'y'. This is not what I want.

I have tried to change the template class 'Function' as follows:

```
    virtual float eval( T const &x, T const &y ) = 0;
```

But the class Foo1 still does not work, the class Foo2 works as in previous case.

1. So it seems that either 'const T &x' or 'T const &x' in the template class implies 'float* const &x' in the derived class. Is this correct?
2. If I want 'const float* &x' (or 'const float* x') in the derived class, what should be my template class Function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

The behaviour you observe is 100% correct as far as the standard is concerned. It's the classic example of "constant pointer" versus "pointer to constant."

Your primary template declares it takes a "reference to `T` through which it cannot modify the `T` object being referred to" (the syntax is `const T &`, equivalent to `T const &`).

Then, you instantiate the template with a type `float*`, i.e. "pointer to `float`." From this follows that the function parameter type after template parameter substitution is indeed "reference to `float *` through which it cannot modify the `float *` begin referred to." There's no way to smuggle "cannot modify the `float` to which the `float *` being referred to points" into there directly.

I see two options. One, if this kind of use is the only use of `T` in `Function`, simply use `const float *` as the template argument, since that's the `T` you really want:

```
class Foo1 : public Function <const float*> {
public:
    Foo1() : Function <const float*> () {}
    virtual float eval( const float* const &x, const float* const &y ) { ... }
    // notice two `const` keywords above: one for the pointed object, one for the reference
};
```

If that is not an option for you (i.e. if you need `float *` somewhere inside `Function` and `const float*` elsewhere), you'll have to use some type traits and modify the parameters of `eval`. Something like this:

```
template <class T>
struct unmodifiable {
  typedef const T &type;
};

template <class T>
struct unmodifiable<T*> {
  typedef const T* const &type; // if you want to keep the reference
  // or just:
  // typedef const T *type;  // if you don't want to bother with the reference for pointer types
};

template <typename T> class Function {
public:
    virtual float eval( typename unmodifiable<T>::type x, typename unmodifiable<T>::type y ) = 0;
};

class Foo1 : public Function <float*> {
public:
    Foo1() : Function <float*> () {}
    virtual float eval( unmodifiable<float*>::type x, unmodifiable<float*>::type y ) { ... }
    // or just spell it out exactly, based on the variant of `unmodifiable` you've chosen, e.g.:
    // virtual float eval (const float *x, const float *y) { ... }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

> It seems that either `const T &x` or `T const &x` in the template class implies `float* const &x` in the derived class. Is this correct?

Yes, that's correct.  The way to think about it is that `T` is always `const`; in your case `T` happens to be a pointer.

> If I want `const float* &x` (or `const float* x`) in the derived class, what should be my template class Function?

Sounds like it should be `class Foo2 : public Function <const float*>`.

Answer (score 0):

A way out is to partially specialize `Function` for pointer types as to use a different signature for `eval`:

```
 template <typename T> class Function<T*> {
    public:
      virtual float eval( const T* x, const T* y ) = 0;
 };
```

Alternatively, you can derive `Foo2` from `Function<const float*>`.